# Encapsulate the reading of objects from database via Spring repository?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

In a Spring Boot application we quite often use methods in different `@Service` classes which read the user from database. Take the following as an example:

```java
@Transactional
public void someMethodInServiceA(long userId) {
  User user = userRepository
    .findById(userId)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(String.format("User not found [id: %d]", userId)));
  // do something with the user object...
}

@Transactional
public void anotherMethodInServiceB(long userId) {
  User user = userRepository
    .findById(userId)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(String.format("User not found [id: %d]", userId)));
  // do something else...
}
```

As the code for fetching the `User` object from the database is almost identical, my first idea was to refactor this to a common service like `UserService` which implements this method, so that there is only one place where the user is actually fetched.

Are there any recommendations from an architectural point-of-view? Maybe other apporaches I haven't considered yet?

Answer (score 1):

creating a UserService is also a good point in case of "hiding" the repository to prevent unwanted operations (e.g. read only methods).

If you need the user serveral times in a request you could also read it once in the controller or starter service and put it in a ThreadLocal for further use.

Or even get the current user in an Interceptor and add it to the current request.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-threadlocal